# Adding up badge totals

Tags: jquery

I have a page that have multiple sections. Each section contains a badge that displays total counts of certain items.

```
<span class="badge">4</span>
```

I need to be able to tell if all of the badges on the page are zeros. Shall I loop though and add them all up to see if the total is over "0"?

```
var cnt = 0;

$('.badge').each(function() {   
   cnt = cnt + $(this).val;
});

if (cnt > 0) {
   // more than 0
}
```

Does not seem very efficient... There's gotta be a better way.

Comment: Looks good to me, don't know how else you would do it.

Comment: you could always put your `if` statement into your loop that way you know immediately when your count goes above 0 and can exit the loop at that stage...

Comment: Well, except that they're `<span>` elements, and they don't have a `value` attribute so the `val()` method isn't going to work; so you should use `text()` instead.

Comment: Does `val` work there? I think you need to use `html()`.

Comment: I wonder if there is some way of using `$("span.badge:not(:contains('0'))").length` that would work? I see an obvious flaw for cases where all badges are either zero or multiples of 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than add them all up, you could loop over them and test each to see if the value is zero.  If you find a non-zero badge value, you can stop testing and react.

Alternately, you could assign an additional class to your badges when the value is output, depending on if they are zero or not.  Something like this:

```
<span class="badge badge-zero">0</span>
<span class="badge badge-nonzero">4</span>
```

Then you can let jQuery do the work for you by selecting a set of non-zero badges:

```
if($("span.badge.badge-nonzero").length > 0){
    //You have some non-zero badges, do something
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to get all the elements you're testing, then filter that collection to remove those that are not zero and compare the lengths of the two sets; summing seems unnecessary:

```
var badges = $('.badge'),
    zeroBadges = badges.filter(function(){
        return parseInt(this.textContent, 10) === 0;
    }),
    allAreZero = badges.length === zeroBadges; // true/false
```

Or you could use `Array.prototype.every()`:

```
var allAreZero = $('.badge').get().every(function (el){
        return parseInt(el.textContent, 10) === 0;
    }); // true/false
```

Or, the same approach in plain JavaScript:

```
var badges = document.querySelectorAll('.badge'),
    allAreZero = Array.prototype.every.call(badges, function (el) {
        return parseInt(el.textContent, 10) === 0;
    });
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).
  - [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).
  - [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent).
  - [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).
- jQuery:

  - [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
  - [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).

Comment: I'm removing my answer in favor of yours, since it covers the same option but is more complete :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use .html() unless you have other html content within the span.

```
var cnt = 0;

$('.badge').each(function() {
   var badge = $(this).html();
   cnt = cnt + parseInt(badge);
});

if (cnt > 0) {
   // more than 0
}
```

Comment: You should always pass a radix to parseInt... `parseInt(badge,10)` ... or coerce to a 32bit integer `~~badge` which will always yeild a number (0 for invalid input) ... also, trim input... `$.trim($(this).html())`